# Input type='date' problems on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, date

When using

```
<input type='month' ng-readonly='vm.isReadonly' required min="{{vm.threeMonthsAgo}}" max='{{vm.oneMonthAhead}}'/>
```

I seem to be encountering some issues on mobile that do not appear on desktop.

For instance, the ng-readonly does not work even when the expression evaluates to true and the min and max attributes seemed to be ignored

I would use

```
<input type='date'>
```

but I only want the user to be able to select month and year. I am also using webshim polyfill.

Everything working as expected on desktop, but using any mobile browser these problems seem to crop up.

If anyone had any advice that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

The date picker is also not working on fire fox.

A good alternative to that is the JQuery-ui datpicker.
Other good date picker is from materialize.

Links to jquery-ui:

https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

And at materialize (special css for mobile):

This link wil take you to the page and you just need to scroll down

http://materializecss.com/forms.html